# Tool to draw component diagrams

Tags: charts, uml, component-diagram

I am looking for some tool to draw component diagram, something like [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) , "a simple markdown-like script language for generating charts from text "

Sadly mermaid doesn't [support component diagram](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/692)

It doesn't need to draw a perfect UML component diagram, just help me draw the main components in the system and the main interactions between the main components.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at plantuml(http://plantuml.com/) and their web server for some tests (http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml)

> PlantUML is a component that allows to quickly write :
>
> ```
> Sequence diagram
> Usecase diagram
> Class diagram
> Activity diagram (here is the legacy syntax)
> Component diagram
> State diagram
> Object diagram
> Deployment diagram 
> Timing diagram
> ```
>
> The following non-UML diagrams are also supported:
>
> ```
> Wireframe graphical interface
> Archimate diagram
> Specification and Description Language (SDL)
> Ditaa diagram
> Gantt diagram 
> MindMap diagram 
> Work Breakdown Structure diagram 
> Mathematic with AsciiMath or JLaTeXMath notation
> ```